# How to combine several partitions into one virtual drive?

Tags: linux, debian, partition, virtual-machine

I have 3 partitions `sda4` 10 Gb ; `sda5` 15 Gb and `sda6` 20 Gb . How to create and mount a virtual hard drive to join several filesystems together under debian8?

Comment: Google for [Logical Volume Management](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM). But it is not trivial to setup if you've never done it. Backups should be in place.

Comment: That being said: If you mount those partitions, isn't the file system tree a virtual drive? What are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you can't delete the three partitions with fdisk, parted, gdisk, or something else and then make one new partition from the empty space?

Comment: @0xSheepdog How do you create a normal partition spanning multiple separate drives?

Comment: I don't know, why do you ask? The details given describe three consecutive partitions on the *same* drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pvcreate /dev/sda4 
pvcreate /dev/sda5 
pvcreate /dev/sda6

vgcreate bigvolgrp /dev/sda4 /dev/sda5 /dev/sda6 

lvcreate -n bigvolume -L 45G bigvolgrp

mkdir /bigstore
mkfs -t ext3 /dev/bigvolgrp/bigvolume
mount /dev/bigvolgrp/bigvolume /bigstore

df -h /bigstore   #to verify
```

Comment: Yup, lvm2 is awesome. This seems a bit redundant though for three contiguous partitions.